# Windows 10 internet speed capped at half the original speed on new PC

Tags: networking, windows-10, desktop-computer, bandwidth

I got a new pc, the internet speed is somehow capped at 5 MB/s on every program .. Torrent, steam, chrome downloads and everything.

I tried with my laptop and other pc and it's runs all good, no internet cap there.

Tried to reinstall drivers, and updating them to the least update... didn't solve the problem.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What's the Windows 10 version? Ethernet or WiFi? Any driver issue? What's the real speed of that connection? Did you change any registry or modify any settings recently?

Comment: @Biswapriyo , my internet speed in normal situations in steam on other devices are +10MB/s , my internet connection is 100Mb/s , i connect via ethernet. 
Windows version:  Windows 10 Home 64bit build 15063

Comment: @Biswapriyo , I didn't modify the registry, and didn't do that much changes on setting.

Comment: Are you getting 5 MB/s _total_, or 5 MB/s _per program_? In other words, if you start 2-3 downloads in different programs at once, does the sum reach 10 MB/s (100 Mbps)?

Comment: @grawity, 5 MB/s total, if one program downloading something .. than every other program that uses internet get unuseable, unless the downloading speed drop less then 5MB/s in the program that downloading. So it's possibly that's is total of 5 MB/s on the whole pc.

Comment: Are you running in 100Mbps full or half duplex? You can run the command `Get-NetAdapter | SELECT name, fullduplex | ft -autosize` in powershell to make sure. Did you try to use another cable?

Comment: @Rik Have done the command you wrote, i got true. The cable works well on other devices

Comment: Any virusscanner or/and firewall other than the default Windows ones?

Comment: @Rik , Turned all of the protection including anti-virus , real-time protection, firewall .. Didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 11):

I was getting less than half the speed I was paying for (150Mbps instead of 400Mbps) for more than a year and had tried everything from constantly calling tech support to swapping out cables and trying other routers.

When I checked, the line “Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level” was set to disabled.

I fixed my speeds by changing that setting from Disabled to Normal using this line in CMD:

**netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal**

[Download Speed Before Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXN1X.jpg)

[Download Speed After Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHpkg.jpg)

Comment: Had been noticing the same issues following an upgrade to 1Gbit over the weekend. I was hitting max peaks of 650Mbits which wasn't noticeable on my 500Mbit line. I followed your steps and this finally got me up to 850Mbit, though that's still below 1Gbit. Will continue to monitor to see if I hit any higher.

Comment: Thanks, I got a similar issue (upload speed blocked at a fraction of what it should be), and this command line fixed the problem. It's incredible such a tiny detail deep down Windows' stack can help unlock the speeds we're supposed to have. Kudos!

Answer (score 4):

windows 10 can improperly set the auto tuning levels.

## Use Cortana to search for “CMD.”

[image: run cmd]

## Right-click on “Command Prompt” and click “Run as administrator.”

[image: run command]

```
netsh interface tcp show global
```

### Look for “Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level” under the results in the Command Prompt window.

[image: auto-tune]
If it’s set to enabled, it’s turned on, and may be causing your internet issues.

## To disable it, run the following command:

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```

the results should be immediate, although it is recommended to restart your PC and power cycle your network gear just to be safe.

### Successful command entered:

[image: success]

If that doesn't work for you, you can try to:
Press Windows key on your keyboard, then type CMD on search, right-click on the result and choose Run as Admin.
Type these following commands to reset your internet/network settings:

netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh winsock reset
Restart your PC and see if the issue is resolved.

Note, both of these solutions are shots in the dark. You have left us with very little information to try and help you with this issue.

references:

https://www.onmsft.com/news/windows-10-limiting-internet-speed-heres-change

https://www.technorms.com/60413/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-limiting-your-internet

https://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/05/windows-10-limiting-internet-speed/

Comment: Have seen this solution many times, didn't work. I tried also to change speed&duplex to different variables, nothing worked. It's giving me real headache.

Comment: Add more info to the question, I'll try to help. Make model of the router. Make model of the laptop, what network adapter is in it? Are you using wired or wireless? This answer was a shot in the dark.

Comment: Internet Connection :   Ethernet output in wall(fiber) -> router -> ethernet cable -> My pc. @Tim_Stewart

Comment: ,Ethernet adapter(+ driver[+ version]) :  Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller 10.10.714.2016

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem during an `scp` copy over my LAN under Windows 10.  I have gigabit adapters on both ends.  Factoring in `scp` overhead, I *should* have been getting a transfer rate between 50-70 MB/sec--wasn't getting that though.

From the network graph in the task manager, my connection was topping out at 100Mbit (~12 MB/sec).  It would occasionally burst to 500Mbit for a few seconds, then fall back to 100M--or less.  Tried swapping out cables, nics, etc... no dice.

Then I tried disabling the `QoS Packet Scheduler` under my network interface.  That fixed it for me!

Surprised that was it though.  From what I recall, Microsoft's QoS Packet Scheduler has been causing similar headaches since Windows XP.  I'd have figured it would be in better shape by now...

Comment: Thanks, worked for me, just had to remove the QOS Packet Scheduler and then disable and re enable the wireles card, went from 30Mbps to 127Mbps

Comment: Worked for me on ethernet line, no reboot needed. Upload immediatelly from 2.5 Mbps to 50 Mbps which is my limit.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps somebody else:
I have a 10Gbe network and could never reach more then 700Mb/s on my windows machine.
Long story (and MS paid support later), I finally started un-installing  stuff.

Norton Utilities was killing my bandwidth by a factor of 8. After the uninstall, I easily achieved 4Gb/s full duplex. (My Linux server on same hardware achieves 9Gb/s, but that's another story.)

Anyways, hope this helps someone else who struggles with this maddening state!

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the  “Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level” and the Qos packets under Network Card Properties.  Disabled and Re-enabled the card.  Worked!

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the "**Remote Access Connection Manager**" service, and I've now shut it down. Download speed doubled in safe mode. So I took a screenshot of "safe" services and compared it to what services are running normally then started turning them off, checking the first half, then the remaining half, and so on, doing Speedtest.net after each batch. It was not just slowing down measured speeds, at times of high traffic even my typing would freeze for short intervals. It pays off to disable services that don't help in any awy.