# Slow internet on desktop, but not on laptop? Where do i look to resolve this?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I've been dealing with internet issues since i moved into my new appartment. So originally i'm obligated to 100/100, which is what i am also receiving - I am reaching those speeds on WiFi with my laptop and on ethernet connection on laptop. When i connect to my desktop with ethernet i am only getting about 10/10?
What could be the reason for this?

Edit:
Fixed by following this thread: [Windows 10 internet speed capped at half the original speed on new PC](https://superuser.com/questions/1330112/windows-10-internet-speed-capped-at-half-the-original-speed-on-new-pc)

Comment: Could you please explain what is 100/100?

Comment: The speed, as in i am paying for 100/100 - however i fixed by following this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/1330112/windows-10-internet-speed-capped-at-half-the-original-speed-on-new-pc

Comment: Try replacing / upgrading the Network Card driver on the Desktop machine.

Comment: Since i sort of fixed it, how do i mark this as fixed?

Comment: Post your edit as an answer and accept it